# Show that $(A \cap B^c)^c=A^c \cup B$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Show that $$(A \cap B^c)^c=A^c \cup B.$$

I am not sure where to start, I believe starting with $x\in(A \cap B^c)^c$ but I am not sure where to go after this.

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{align}
x \in (A \cap B^c)^c &\iff x \notin A \cap B^c \\
&\iff x \notin A \text{ or } x \notin B^c \\
&\iff x \in A^c \text{ or } x \in B \\
&\iff x \in A^c \cup B.
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $x\in U$.

$$x\in (A\cup B_C)_C \iff$$

$$x \notin  (A\cap B_C)  \iff $$

$$x\notin A \; \vee \; x\notin B_C \iff$$

$$x\in A_C \; \vee \; x\in B \iff$$

$$x\in A_C \cup B$$

thus

$$(A\cup B_C)_C = A_C \cup B$$